# Jenkins: Build merge commit for Github Pull requests

Tags: git, jenkins, github

Github creates a commit that is a merge of the PR branch with the base branch (eg develop) every time the PR branch is pushed to, so that it can show if there are merge conflicts in develop.

Is it possible to get Jenkins to build and run tests (etc) on this commit rather than the head of the PR branch. That way it will will detect any errors that would result from the merge itself.

We can't do an local merge with the develop branch every time as sometimes PR's have a different base branch, or Jenkins needs to get the base branch of that PR and do a local merge.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this is something you want? I am not sure how Jenkins would handle it if there were merge conflicts.

But it looks like this article addresses most of what you are after
https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/dont-phunk-my-stable-branch-jenkins-pre-tested-commits-stop-breaking-stable-branches

There is a GIT option called Merge before build, which allows you to choose a branch to merge in before building 
You can set it up like suggested in the article and just not allow it to do the push to a remote.